# Form data not sent in mail while attachment is sent in PHP

Tags: php

I am tyring to have a contact form on my website having option for visitor to send attachment with their information. I tried but couldn't succeed. The problem i am having is that the file is sent to the email but the form data and email subject is not sent with the attachment.

HTML:

```
    <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="do_send.php">
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </label>

<label>

  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
  </label>


  <label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  </label>

  <label>
  <input type="file" name="my_file" />
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

do_send.php:

```
        <?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file']))
{

//get file details we need
$file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
$file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
$file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
$file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

if($file_error>0)
{
    die('upload error');
}

     //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
$handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


# Mail headers should work with most clients (including thunderbird)
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject:".$subject."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $MESSAGE_BODY."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
$headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
$headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--"; 

if ($_POST["email"]!='') { 
    $ToEmail = 'info@mywebiste.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Website contact form'; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br><br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Age: ".$_POST["age"]."<br>"; 

    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $headers) or die ("Failure");
    echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
    window.location='index.html'</script>";
    return true;

} else{ 
echo "<script> alert('Temporary problem, try again!');
window.location='index.html'</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Kindly point out where i am doing mistake. I am in learning stage please help me solving this issue. Please guide me where to do amendment in the do_send.php so that the form data and email subject is also sent with the attachment.

Comment: There are a host of possible improvements, but I *think* you should only use a single value for a boundary, as the message will only need a single boundary `md5` value, rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$nom = $_POST['lastName'];
$prenom = $_POST['firstName'];
$from_email = $_POST['email']; //sender email

if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file']))
{
    $recipient_email = 'youremail@exemple.com'; //recipient email
    $subject = 'Inscription Etudiant'; //subject of email
    $message = 'This is body of the message'; //message body

$message = 'Nom: '.$nom."\n";
$message .= 'Prenom: '.$prenom."\n";
$message .= 'Email: '.$from_email;

    //get file details we need
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    $user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if($file_error>0)
    {
        die('upload error');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


        $boundary = md5("YADIStudio"); 
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
if ($sentMail) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to youremail@exemple.com');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php
}

}

?>

<--! YADI Studio Agency Copyright 2015 -->
```

Comment: Also possibly remove the copyright notice too, it does make it look like you copy and pasted this code from a PHP guide website. (Copyright is for YADI Studio Agency)

Comment: Please give some hints how your code differs from the one in the question so everyone can learn something from your solution.